# Output parameters for user-assigned-identity in bicep?

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-managed-identity, azure-bicep

I'm trying to retrieve the **Client ID** of a Managed Identity created with Azure Bicep. But the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.managedidentity/userassignedidentities?pivots=deployment-language-bicep) doesn't give any information about the output parameters. Am I missing something? How can I retrieve the client id after defining the Managed Identity in bicep ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The clientId is available on the properties of the identity:

```
param identityName string

resource identity 'Microsoft.ManagedIdentity/userAssignedIdentities@2022-01-31-preview' = {
  name: identityName
  location: resourceGroup().location
}

output clientId string = identity.properties.clientId
```