How can I assign multiple Entra admins, including user-assigned identity, to SQL Server using Bicep?
I'm deploying a Bicep template using a service principal with Contributor role on the subscription.
The template creates a user-assigned identity that needs to access the database from an Azure Function app to create tables and perform CRUD operations.
The service principal (SP) doesn't have permission to create or modify Entra ID groups.
I want both members of my team and the user-assigned identity to be able to access the database, with this setup performed as part of the CI/CD pipeline. Currently, I don't see how this is possible, as the only way of assignment multiple admins is through an Entra ID group (and the SP can't include the user-assigned identity in it)?
Is there any way to grant both team members and the user-assigned identity access to the database via Entra ID authentication, without being able to modify groups?
resource userAssignedIdentity 'Microsoft.ManagedIdentity/userAssignedIdentities@2023-01-31' existing = {
  name: userAssignedIdentityName
}

resource databaseServer 'Microsoft.Sql/servers@2023-05-01-preview' = {
  name: '${toLower(databaseServerName)}-${resourceNameSuffix}'
  location: location
  properties: {
    // administratorLogin: sqlAdministratorLogin
    administratorLoginPassword: sqlAdministratorPassword
    version: '12.0'
    minimalTlsVersion: '1.2'
    publicNetworkAccess: 'Enabled'
    administrators: {
      administratorType: 'ActiveDirectory'
      principalType: 'Application'
      login: userAssignedIdentity.name
      sid: userAssignedIdentity.properties.principalId
      tenantId: tenant().tenantId
      azureADOnlyAuthentication: true
    }
    restrictOutboundNetworkAccess: 'Disabled'
  }
}


you could grant admin permission to the SP running your pipleine then connect to sql db and grant permission to the managed identity and the users

see this one as well: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76996864/4167200

@Thomas Thank you. How would you add a group to SQL server as an admin, so the members can access the query editor of the SQL  database? Furthermore, would you run this command from Bicep or via a dedicated GitHub Actions step? If from Bicep, can you show an example? I’m already familiar with deployment scripts, but find them hard to use

you need to connect to sql server and grant permission via t-sql command. so prob easier to use a dedicated github action
